# About pronunciation of 'g' in words ending in -ng

Tags: pronunciation

Some people pronounce the *g* at the end of words like *spring* and *listening* as  [g] (as in *guard*) instead of [ŋ]. First, I thought only some Russians tend to do this, but the other day I heard a British person doing the same thing in a recording.

Now I'm confused. Which is correct?

Answer (score 2):

The *g* that is part of the *ng* digraph in words ending with *-ng* should always be pronounced as [ŋ], never as [g].

In fact, one of the only places where it gets pronounced kind of that way is in ***finger***, where in fact you have both: [ŋg].  Notice how that is in the middle of the word. You never do that at the end of a word; an English mouth rebels against that combo.

Comment: There are some British accents which do pronounce the [g]: Birmingham/Black Country, for example.

Comment: There are also quite a few American dialects that replace that sound with [ɪn] or [ən] (commonly called g-dropping). Among them are Southern American English, African American Vernacular English, and the sort of imitation "common man" accent often taken up by politicians during election seasons.

Comment: Andrew is quite right. Some Liverpudlian accents also pronounce the *g*

Comment: Various Australian accents pronounce _something_ and _anything_ as with a final [k], i.e., a devoiced [g] (e.g., somethi[ŋk]).

Comment: Final velar ŋg clusters, like final labial mb clusters, lost the stop (_sing, thumb_) long ago, leaving only the nasal. This made /ŋ/ a phoneme in English, contrasting with /ŋg/ in _finger_, which doesn't rhyme with _singer_. In fact, there's a minimal pair: _longer_ meaning 'more long' has /ŋg/, whereas _longer_ meaning 'one who longs' has only /ŋ/.

Comment: In standard AmE, 'anger', 'linger', also are like 'finger' (velar nasal-stop pair). 'danger' , 'avenger' have much different mapping back to pronunciation. Any other exceptions?

Comment: @Mitch Exceptions which way? There are about 1000 words with /ŋg/, if that is what you mean. If you mean how many /ndʒ/ or /nʒ/ words, that is something else.

Comment: @tchrist: I thought you were pointing out that __finger__ is "one of the only places where it gets pronounced kind of that way" namely [ŋg], and I was trying to come up with those few others. But are you saying there are -many- others like that?

Comment: Seems the answer is not that straight forward--there are many variations and not a single 'correct' way.

Comment: @Mitch The *singer* and *ringer* pattern is **much** more common than the one in *finger* and *linger*, but once you relax the *-inger* restriction, /ŋg/ occurs in many other words: *angle, bingo, congress, English, fungus, gangrene, hunger,* etc. Compare *clinger, dinger, finger, flinger, linger, minger, pinger, ringer, stinger, swinger, winger, zinger* **versus** *ginger, harbinger, infringer, porringer, wharfinger*.